# Intellij IDEA Kotlin - How to comment in same column?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin, comments

I want comments to be intended when using `Ctrl+/`, it **works** for `Java` **but not for** `Kotlin` code, I have done as mentioned in [help-desk](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-code-editor.html) (Note: I'm using `Intellij Ultimate 2018.2`)

> To configure settings for commenting behavior in Java, use options in the Comment Code section, on the Code Generation tab located in File | Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Java.

Marked `Add a space at comment start` in `Commented Code` section,
I couldn't find any comment code configuration in `Kotlin Code Style`

[image]

For example in `Kotlin`:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // Desired comment
//    After Using Ctrl+/
}
```

But works in `Java`:

```
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Works fine using Ctrl+/
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Still not solved

Answer (score 1):

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2018.**3**, but I believe this is still available in IDEA 2018.2.

In Settings, `Editor` -> `Code Style` -> `Kotlin` -> `Wrapping and Braces`, under `Keep when reformatting`, *un*tick `Comment at first column`.

[image: Comment at first column is closed, and the sample shows what we expected.]

**Update**: I found this is not at coding... But take place after `Code` -> `Reformat Code` :-(

Answer (score 1):

In `Wrapping and Braces` this option is not working for me while use keyboard shortcut, the setting is under:

`Editor -> Code Style -> Kotlin -> Code Generation`

and untick the option: `Line comment at first column`, done!